# Select count on table_link as bridge many to many relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that have relation manu to many like this

**1st : Table request**

```
MariaDB [ittresnamuda]> select ID_REQUEST, NUMBER_OF_LETTER, TANGGAL_TERIMA FROM tb_requestfix limit 10;
+------------+------------------+---------------------+
| ID_REQUEST | NUMBER_OF_LETTER | TANGGAL_TERIMA      |
+------------+------------------+---------------------+
|         32 |              001 | 2016-01-02 09:00:00 |
|         33 |              002 | 2016-01-02 09:00:00 |
|         34 |              003 | 2016-01-02 13:00:00 |
|         47 |              004 | 2016-01-04 09:00:00 |
|         48 |              005 | 2016-01-04 10:49:00 |
|         52 |              006 | 2016-01-04 11:14:00 |
|         53 |              007 | 2016-01-04 13:50:00 |
|         54 |              008 | 2016-01-04 16:17:00 |
|         55 |              009 | 2016-01-04 16:28:00 |
|         56 |              010 | 2016-01-05 13:12:00 |
+------------+------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2nd. Table Item**

```
MariaDB [ittresnamuda]> select * from tb_item_request ;
+---------+-----------+
| ID_ITEM | NAMA_ITEM |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Login     |
|       2 | Printer   |
|       3 | Monitor   |
|       4 | Computer  |
|       5 | Network   |
|       6 | Lain-lain |
+---------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, I create a helper table to manage them into one to many relationship. This is the table.

**Table link**

```
MariaDB [ittresnamuda]> select * from tb_link_item_request LIMIT 10;
+-----+------------+---------+
| ID  | id_request | id_item |
+-----+------------+---------+
| 125 |         34 |       6 |
| 146 |         32 |       4 |
| 147 |         33 |       1 |
| 148 |         47 |       4 |
| 153 |         48 |       6 |
| 154 |         52 |       1 |
| 155 |         53 |       2 |
| 156 |         53 |       6 |
| 157 |         54 |       4 |
| 158 |         55 |       3 |
+-----+------------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I want to count the record of request based the item, month and the year of request, like this.

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+
| ID_ITEM | NAMA_ITEM | TOTAL_OF_ITEM |
+---------+-----------+---------------+
|       1 | Login     |       2       |
|       2 | Printer   |       1       |
|       3 | Monitor   |       1       |
|       4 | Computer  |       3       |
|       5 | Network   |       0       |
|       6 | Lain-lain |       3       |
+---------+-----------+---------------+
```

So far, I tried like this,

```
MariaDB [ittresnamuda]> SELECT b.ID_ITEM, b.NAMA_ITEM, COUNT(a.id_item) AS TOTAL_ITEM
-> FROM tb_link_item_request a
->
-> INNER JOIN tb_item_request b
-> ON a.id_item = b.ID_ITEM
->
-> INNER JOIN tb_requestfix c
-> ON a.id_request = c.ID_REQUEST
->
-> WHERE a.id_item = 1 AND MONTH(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA) = 01 AND YEAR(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA) = 2016;

+---------+-----------+------------+
| ID_ITEM | NAMA_ITEM | TOTAL_ITEM |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 | LOGIN     |          2 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any help it so appreciated,

Comment: So, what is the wrong with your solution ?

Comment: I just can return one record, but I need all the record of tb_item

Comment: you use `WHERE a.id_item = 5` in your query, Why ?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add a group by clause and remove the where clause:

```
SELECT b.ID_ITEM, b.NAMA_ITEM, YEAR(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA), MONTH(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA), COUNT(a.id_item) AS TOTAL_ITEM
FROM tb_link_item_request a
INNER JOIN tb_item_request b ON a.id_item = b.ID_ITEM
INNER JOIN tb_requestfix c ON a.id_request = c.ID_REQUEST
GROUP BY b.id_item, b.NAMA_ITEM, MONTH(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA) YEAR(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA)
```

Comment: If you have a followup question, then pls do not edit my answer to ask it, edit your own question and the leave a comment below the answer to check out the updated question!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.ID_ITEM, b.NAMA_ITEM, COALESCE(COUNT(a.id_item),0) AS TOTAL_ITEM
   FROM tb_item_request b
   LEFT JOIN tb_link_item_request a ON a.id_item = b.ID_ITEM
   LEFT JOIN tb_requestfix c ON a.id_request = c.ID_REQUEST
  WHERE COALESCE(MONTH(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA),-1) = 01 AND COALESCE(YEAR(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA),-1) = 2016
  GROUP BY b.ID_ITEM, b.NAMA_ITEM;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT b.ID_ITEM, b.NAMA_ITEM, COUNT(a.id_item) AS TOTAL_ITEM
 FROM tb_item_request b
LEFT JOIN tb_link_item_request a ON a.id_item = b.ID_ITEM
LEFT JOIN tb_requestfix c ON a.id_request = c.ID_REQUEST AND MONTH(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA) = 01 AND YEAR(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA) = 2016
group by b.id_item, b.NAMA_ITEM
```

Comment: This is against the sql standard and may only run in mysql if full group by sql mode is not set. Luckily, this mode is turned on by default in the newer versions of mysql.

Comment: why it is against the sql standard? @Shadow

Comment: Does it now considered as standard ? @Shadow

Answer (score 0):

And this if you do not need `Group By` clause:

```
SELECT distinct b.ID_ITEM, b.NAMA_ITEM,
(select COUNT(id_item) from tb_link_item_request a1 where a1.id_item = a.id_item) AS TOTAL_ITEM
FROM tb_item_request b
LEFT JOIN tb_link_item_request a ON a.id_item = b.ID_ITEM
LEFT JOIN tb_requestfix c ON a.id_request = c.ID_REQUEST AND MONTH(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA) = 01 AND YEAR(c.TANGGAL_TERIMA) = 2016
```